# Is there common cause of stable sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I know that sort algorithm can be stable or unstable. I know difference between these. We can  change unstable algorithm into stable by replace `switching` procedure to `insert` another words using `linked list`.
But I wanted to know is there common cause of stable sort algorithm? Maybe someone can share some information or explain?

Comment: What do you mean "cause" of stable sort algorithm? An algorithm is either stable or it isn't, depending on how the algorithm works. But I wouldn't call that a cause.

Comment: I mean signs that make algorithm stable. For example "algorithm that has only `>=` operator will be stable". It's hard to explain but something like this.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to make general statements about that. The best way is to reason about how the algorithm works and figure out whether it's stable or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if the algorithm swaps two elements without having already checked the elements in the middle, it's not stable. This mainly applies to in-place algorithms, but for non-in-place algorithms, you can check whether any element is inserted into the output in such a way that an equal element could be on the wrong side.

Think of [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). At the very beginning you can swap the left-most and right-most elements (without having done much else), so it's not stable.

Think of [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). You'll never swap two elements without first checking all elements in between, so it's stable.

While this is sort of vague, there are plenty of sorting algorithms that all work fundamentally different, so it has to be sort of vague.

Also, don't take this as a rule, it's just a general observation (and it may indeed not work for certain algorithms). You'd really just have to understand the algorithm in-depth to know whether or not it's stable, or check what someone else said it is.

> We can change an unstable algorithm into a stable one by replace `switching` procedure to `insert` another words using linked list.

I don't fully understand that statement, but I can almost guarantee that it doesn't hold for all sorting algorithms.

To convert any (comparison-based) unstable sorting algorithm to a stable one, you can add an additional parameter to your comparison, which could just be the index in the original array.